# How can you prove the triangle sum theorem?

Tags: geometry

Some things to consider:

-This theorem has proved very, very many theorems many of which with trig, so you can't use any theorems that have been proven with the triangle sum theorem.

-The Triangle Sum Theorem states that the measures of the angles in a triangle (in degrees) must add to $180^\circ$.

This is a theorem therefore it already has been proven, so what would that proof be? I duly noted that this is an elementary topic, but it seems that all my ways of proving it failed because at lease one of the steps in the proof had a reason that had been proved already by none other than the $\Delta $ sum theorem.

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry/parallel-and-perpendicular-lines/triang_prop_tut/v/proof-sum-of-measures-of-angles-in-a-triangle-are-180

Comment: A common way to do it is to use the theorems about angles around parallel lines, using the base of the triangle as the first line and the second line will pass through the remaining vertex.

Comment: Note that any proof of this theorem must use the parallel postulate in some way, because it ain't true in hyperbolic geometry, which satisfies the other Euclidean axioms. Also note that the khan academy proof plays a little fast and loose with questions of between-ness; there probably should have been an invocation or two of the crossbar theorem or something like that.

Comment: On triangle ABC, try drawing a line through A parallel to BC. Now, you just need to use alternate interior angles. (To those who care, that first sentence uses a form of the parallel postulate. Also, alternate interior angles can be proven using the parallel postulate.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will assume you are working in Euclidean Geometry (since this is untrue in [Non-Euclidean Geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Euclidean_geometry)).

In particular, you have the use of the fifth postulate which reads:

> "*If a straight line crossing two straight lines makes the interior angles on the same side less than two right angles, the two straight lines, if extended indefinitely, meet on that side on which are the angles less than the two right angles*."

You could work in a setting where this is untrue (as detailed in the wiki-link above).

[image: Triangle postulate]

Let $\overline{AB}\parallel \overline{CD}$.  You should know then that $\angle ABC = \angle DCB$.  You should also know that $\angle CAB = \angle ECD$.

By the definition of a right angle, $\angle ACE = 180^\circ = \angle BCA + \angle DCB + \angle ECD = \angle ACB + \angle CBA + \angle BAC$